# Bitcoin Core banned all peers, so I can't sync

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, p2p, banscore

I started downloading the chain and got to 14%. The download stopped and still shows 7% per hour but it does not move.

I checked and it banned all the peers and every time I unban them, they just get banned again. What is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Peers can get blocked for multiple reasons

- sending too many invalid blocks
- sending too many malformed messages
- using too much bandwidth (e.g. your `maxuploadtarget` setting)

and probably others.

There are logs which may be helpful and you can review available options

> ```
> -banscore=<n>
> Threshold for disconnecting misbehaving peers (default: 100)
>
> -bantime=<n>
> Number of seconds to keep misbehaving peers from reconnecting  
> (default:86400)
>
>
> -whitelist=<IP address or network>
> Whitelist peers connecting from the given IP address (e.g. 
> 1.2.3.4) or CIDR notated network (e.g. 1.2.3.0/24). Can be 
> specified multiple times. Whitelisted peers cannot be DoS
> banned and their transactions are always relayed, even if 
> they are already in the mempool, useful e.g. for a gateway
> ```

Comment: where can I find my maxuploudtarget?
I just -reindex now to see what will happen